# Explain why $\Pr(H_2|H_1)=\int_0^1\Pr(H_2|P=p)f_{P|H_1}(p)dp$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, bayes-theorem

**Problem**: we produced biased coins and the probability of Heads has the following PDF: $f_{P}(p)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
pe^{p}, & p\in[0,1],\\
0, & p\notin[0,1]
\end{array}\right.$

We know that $\Pr(H_1)=e-2$, where the event $H_1$ - Heads in the first toss of a coin. It's found using total probability law.

We also know that $f_{P|H_{1}}(p|H_{1})=\frac{p^{2}e^{p}}{e-2}$ (the Bayes' rule was to the rescue here)

Finally, we need to find $\Pr(H_2|H_1)$. The book suggests that

$\Pr(H_2|H_1)=\int_{0}^{1}\Pr(H_2|P=p)f_{P|H_{1}}dp$

I understand every component of this formula and the limits of integration are obvious. But what is that formula? I can't recoginze either the definition of conditional probability here or a Bayes' variant or the total probability law.

What is that here?

Comment: The general formula is $$P(H_2|H_1)=\int_0^1P(H_2|H_1,P=p)f_{P|H_1}(p)dp$$ and in your case,  $$P(H_2|H_1,P=p)=P(H_2|P=p)$$ Are these two identities ringing any bell?

Comment: @Did I've never seen the general formula that you mentioned, that's the problem. I understand $P(H_2|H_1,P=p)=P(H_2|P=p)$, but where doest  the formula come from?

Comment: You might have seen and/or wish to sharpen your intuition on the discrete case, which reads $$P(A\mid B)=\sum_kP(A\mid B,X=x_k)P(X=x_k\mid B)$$ for every discrete random variable $X$ with values $(x_k)$. Clearer now?

Comment: @Did Need to think it over... Thanks, anyway!